# Do I have to manually cancel membership on each Stack Exchange site where I was active?

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I want to permanently delete my account across **all** Stack Exchange sites using the procedure described here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/223253 . For every site on which I was registered where I have not voted or posted more than once, I used the *delete* link in the profile to delete myself from that site. I then used the contact form to request deletion of the rest.

I have now received a link to schedule the deletion of my account, which I have activated. Upon activating the link, I was presented with this message:

> This account is scheduled to be deleted in 23 hours. To cancel deletion, click here.
>
> **IMPORTANT: If you've requested deletion on other Stack Exchange sites, you'll need to cancel those separately by visiting each site's profile.**

I don't understand the part that says *you'll need to cancel those separately by visiting each site's profile*.

I want to delete my account from **all** Stack Exchange sites. The few sites where I was not active, I have manually deleted. There is no other option on any of the other profiles (where I was active) to delete myself from those sites. Will the deletion I have activated now remove my account from **all** Stack Exchange sites? What do you mean by me visiting each site's profile? Am I maybe supposed to send a separate deletion request message to each site on which I was active?

Comment: @rene most likely this whole process is for one single site of of his 32 accounts, where he sent the "contact us" request. So yes, this process must be done for each and every account, as the answer on the dupe clearly says.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you. I'll go ahead and nuke them one by one.

Comment: I edited the original instructions to which I linked to make clear the contact form method only applies to the respective site.